# Reduce the height of title/head-bars and their corner radius in Gnome 3.19+

Tags: linux, gnome, themes, gnome-shell

Is there an entry in `gnome-shell.css` that control the corner radius of "title bar" (if I use the correct term) of most windows?

As shown in the picture

[image: An example of the corner radius of "title-bars"].

I want to reduce the corner radius, since I reduce the height of title bars. Now the corner looks pretty ugly (personally I don't like rounded corners).

I have checked almost all entries, however, still not finding it. Anyone having ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. It can be done by adding configurations in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`:
the entry `border-radius` is to reduce the radius of corners; the others are to reduce the height of title-bar (which I guess most guys suffer from in gnome 3.18+, when there is no .xml available for adjustment).

```
/* Locate in "~/.config/gtk-3.0/" to decrease title bar in gnome 3 */
/* INFO: valid for Gnome 3.19+ */


/* shrink headebars */
headerbar {
    min-height: 28px;
    border-radius: 2px;  /* remove the rounded corners*/
}

headerbar entry,
headerbar spinbutton,
headerbar button,
headerbar separator {
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}

/* shrink ssd titlebars */
.default-decoration {
    min-height: 0; /* let the entry and button drive the titlebar size */ 
}

.default-decoration .titlebutton {
    min-height: 16px; /* tweak these two props to reduce button size */
    min-width: 16px;
    border-radius: 1px;
}
```